# Entity Framework 5.0 - 1 to 1 Relation is NULL without reason

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, nullreferenceexception

I've searched many questions here, that sounded similar to mine, but none if it matched my problem, so I hope for some help in this ticket..

I use EF Code First and try to map it to an existing (legacy) MySQL Database. Works fine on my properties except for one, and I can't figure out why..

Model that is null:

```
[Table("einheitenstamm")]
public class Unit : ClassicEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column("estID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("estEinheit")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Model containing the reference to Unit:

```
[Table("artikeldaten_preise")]
public class ArticlePrice : ClassicEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("einheit")]
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; } /* is always null!!!!! */

    [Column("preisliste")]
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Pricelist Pricelist { get; set; } /* gets loaded without problems */

    [Column("artikel")]
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; } /* gets loaded without problems */


    [Column("preis")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Database Table Create:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `artikeldaten_preise` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `preisliste` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `artikel` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `preis` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    `einheit` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `changed` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sys_deleted` BIT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
    `sys_changedfrom` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `sys_changedat` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `artikel` (`artikel`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `preisliste` (`preisliste`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `einheit` (`einheit`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

Code:

```
var units = from unit in context.Units
            where unit.Id == 4
            select unit;

foreach (var unit in units)
    Console.WriteLine(unit.Id + ": " + unit.Name); /* works */


var prices = from price in context.ArticlePrices
             select price;

foreach (var price in prices.ToList()) /* price.Unit = NULL ........... */
    MessageBox.Show(price.Article.Description + " " + price.Price + "/"
                    + price.Unit.Name + " in pricelist '"
                    + price.Pricelist.Name + "'");
```

Can anybody please tell me what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the relations explicitly and create an xxId property for each navigation property that you can then decorate with the corresponding ForeignKey attribute. No need for "real" foreign keys here..

```
[Table("artikeldaten_preise")]
public class ArticlePrice : ClassicEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("einheit")]
    public int UnitId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UnitId")]
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }

    [Column("preisliste")]
    public int PricelistId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PricelistId")]
    public virtual Pricelist Pricelist { get; set; }

    [Column("artikel")]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ArticleId")]
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }

    [Column("preis")]
    public double Price { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var prices = from price in context.ArticlePrices.Include("Price.Unit")
                     select price;
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't fix it. I think I made a mistake on decorating the ForeignKey property. It seems like it tries to lazy load the Navigation Properties according to the Id of the article price instead of the ForeignKey..

Do I need a _real_ FK to solve this in EF? Because if I just give it the column name in the table EF throws me an exception telling me, that the "ForeignKey" doesn't exist if I try to set it to "preisliste".. >/